# nc vs ncat read/write

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I have been using -i option to delay write/read sequence in order to read response from a device.

Because this version of nc doesn't support milliseconds as a parameter to -i option, I found ncat will do it. So I installed it along with nmap package. But it looks like there is difference in raspbian jessie nc (symlinked to nc.openbsd) and ncat installed with nmap.

If I execute command

```
phy@domainX:~ $ echo "V" | nc -v -i1 192.168.1.54 23008

Connection to 192.168.1.54 23008 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

AD=544
```

I get response according to above. If I do the same execution with ncat I don't get response

```
phy@domainX:~ $ echo "V" | ncat -v -i1 192.168.1.54 23008

Ncat: Version 6.47 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )

Ncat: Connected to 192.168.1.54:23008.

Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms).
```

in addition, if I execute following

```
phy@domainX:~ $ ncat -v 192.168.1.54 23008

Ncat: Version 6.47 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )

Ncat: Connected to 192.168.1.54:23008.

V

AD=545

^C

phy@domainX:~ $
```

Is there any way to get ncat read the response similar to nc above?

Comment: Seems there is no one still using old-old stable Raspbian Jessie. Have you considered to upgrade to up to date Raspbian Buster?

Comment: Certainly I have been thinking about to upgrade the distro, but not done mainly due to this RPI is located on a remote site.

Comment: this is not an answer to my question, but I have found a workaround to do the same thing using curl. I share this workaround if somebody finds it useful.  phy@domainX:~ $ echo "V" | /usr/bin/curl -s -m0.2 telnet://192.168.1.54:23008